# I want to point exact location of an IP address on Google maps

Tags: maps, location, ip, street-address

I want to point exact location of an IP address on Google Maps or any other service. I want the marker to be exact. How can I do it, using which service, either at cost or free of cost?

Comment: It will never be absolutely exact. Someone could use wifi or cable or laser IP on several kilometers.

Comment: Even though I can't help, I think this post is a bit demanding. People usually reply fast. If your project is based on it maybe do not count on a non-commercial way of getting information.

Comment: You need to define "exact" (to within how many meters).  You need to define how reliable it needs to be (95% correct?).  And you need to be less demanding.

Comment: I want the location to be correct to 100 mtrs maximum.. And if someone is providing any paid service for this, i am ready to opt it.

Comment: I.P address locations are not exact enough to be accurate within 100 meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make the answer official, no geo-location service can reliably provide that kind of accuracy.  You can be reasonably sure of the city/town and that's about it...  assuming no deliberate attempt to hide their location like [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), [TOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)), etc.

If your users are cooperating, then you could build your own geo-location service that, for example, uses GPS from a phone when it is connected through a WiFi router and reports that back to your service.

Comment: @SureshSharma: would you accept this answer? I think it is unlikely to be bettered by another.

Answer (score 1):

fecth geolocations tags and youre good to go